# Узорчатый тюль

Tags: морфология

Слово "тюль" мужского рода. Почему же многие употребляют его в форме женского.
Если по аналогии со словами "моль", боль, соль, то мы же не говорим кроль, ноль, киль, куль в женском роде. Откуда такая тенденция?

Comment: Впервые слышу, чтобы ПРАКТИЧЕСКИ ВСЕ говорили в женском роде. Говорят некоторые малограмотные личности. Ну так "тубаретка" и "ризетка" тоже говорят...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее по аналогии со словом "ткань", да и вообще, вид у тюля довольно женский. Даже Лесков в одной из своих повестей написал, - "По груди что-то серело, точно тюль, и эта тюль двигалась..." Но разговор о причинах произношения того или иного слова в языке - это всегда разновидность софистики, предположений море, а истина где-то рядом.

Answer (score 5):

Можно предположить, что люди просто не знают, что это слово мужского рода. Например, многие ученики совсем недавно узнали, что правильно говорить не тапок, а тапка.

Comment: По-моему, "тапок" и "тапка" равнозначные варианты. Где-то тут это даже обсуждалось.

Comment: Да, просто не знают, я думаю. У меня родители употребляли это слово в женском роде, и я только во взрослом возрасте узнала, что это не правильно. У других тоже иногда замечаю подобные ошибки, которые идут из детства - типа шампунь ж.р., консерва.

Comment: В детстве тоже слышала от родителей только "новая тюль". В свое время пришлось переучиваться. Пришлось переучиваться. Ассоциация скорее со словом штора.

Answer (score 4):

> Почему же ***практически все*** употребляют его в форме женского.

Я "тюль" в женском не употребляю. И слово "практически" вместо слово "почти" - тоже.

Answer (score 2):

Если ориентироваться на **всех**, тогда и спрашивать не нужно!!!
Есть словари, есть норма, которую НУЖНО, независимо от ВСЕХ соблюдать!!!
И тогда не будешь морщиться от многочисленных ОТКЛОНЕНИЙ в правописании и произношении русского языка.

Answer (score 2):

Это слово ассоциируется со словом "занавеска", вот и говорят в ж.р.